# How to do a conditional, complex "combining" of two columns in pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `pandas` DataFrame `df`:

```
cit1   cgen1   cit2   cgen2   pair1   pair2

c1     male    c25    female  A       B        (+)
c2     female  c25    female  A       B
c5     male    c25    female  A       B
c5     male    c26    male    A       B

c1     male    c1     male    A       C        (*)
c2     female  c3     female  A       C

c1     male    c13    male    C       D
c7     female  c13    male    C       D
c8     male    c17    female  C       D

c8     male    c17    female  E       F
c12    male    c17    female  E       F
...
```

(note that the blank space is arbitrarily inserted for the convenience of the readers)

Here, for an easier understanding, treat `cit1` and `cgen1` as a pair, `cit2` and `cgen2` as a pair, and `pair1` and `pair2` as a pair.

My desired result DataFrame `df2` is the following:

```
cit    cgen    pair1    pair2

c1     male    A        B         (&)
c2     female  A        B
c5     male    A        B
c25    female  A        B         (&&)
c26    male    A        B

c1     male    A        C
c2     female  A        C
c3     female  A        C

c1     male    C        D
c7     female  C        D
c8     male    C        D
c13    male    C        D
c17    female  C        D

c8     male    E        F
c12    male    E        F
c17    female  E        F
...
```

Essentially, I want to form union columns `cit` and `cgen` by combining `cit1` and `cit2` (for `cit`), and the corresponding `cgen1` and `cgen2` (for `cgen`) per unique pair of `pair1` and `pair2` values.

For example, `c1` and `male` from `cit1` and `cgen1` in `(+)` are registered as `cit` and `cgen` in `(&)`.

`c25` and `female` from `cit2` and `cgen2` in `(+)` are registered as `cit` and `cgen` in `(&&)`.

There exist also some cases where `cit1 == cit2` for a certain pair, displayed by `(*)`.

I have tried different functions, such as `pandas.merge()`, `pandas.concat()`, and `pandas.groupby()`, but nothing seemed to produce what I intend to produce. (I won't necessarily write the attempted codes here, as they all produced nonsense. I can put it in the comments by request if necessary.)

Any insights on how to tackle this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Your rules for merging cit1 and cit2 and also rules for merging cgen1 and cgen2 are not clear.

Comment: @rnso oops you are right. I will edit that in the post. Basically, I'm treating `cit1` and `cgen1` as a pair, and `cit2` and `cgen2` as a pair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`wide_to_long`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) for reshape, then remove duplicates by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html), sorting by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and last create default index:

```
df = (pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), stubnames=['cit','cgen'], i='index', j='tmp')
        .reindex(['cit','cgen','pair1','pair2'], axis=1)
        .drop_duplicates(["pair1", "pair2", "cgen", "cit"])
        .sort_values(["pair1", "pair2", "cit"], ignore_index=True)
        .reset_index(drop=True)
        )
print (df)
    cit    cgen pair1 pair2
0    c1    male     A     B
1    c2  female     A     B
2   c25  female     A     B
3   c26    male     A     B
4    c5    male     A     B
5    c1    male     A     C
6    c2  female     A     C
7    c3  female     A     C
8    c1    male     C     D
9   c13    male     C     D
10  c17  female     C     D
11   c7  female     C     D
12   c8    male     C     D
13  c12    male     E     F
14  c17  female     E     F
15   c8    male     E     F
```

Or you can `rename` columns filtered by subset, join by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), remove duplicates and sorting:

```
d = {'cit1':'cit','cit2':'cit','cgen1':'cgen','cgen2':'cgen'}
df = (pd.concat([df[['cit1','cgen1','pair1','pair2']].rename(columns=d),
                df[['cit2','cgen2','pair1','pair2']].rename(columns=d)])
        .drop_duplicates(["pair1", "pair2", "cgen", "cit"])
        .sort_values(["pair1", "pair2", "cit"], ignore_index=True))
print (df)
    cit    cgen pair1 pair2
0    c1    male     A     B
1    c2  female     A     B
2   c25  female     A     B
3   c26    male     A     B
4    c5    male     A     B
5    c1    male     A     C
6    c2  female     A     C
7    c3  female     A     C
8    c1    male     C     D
9   c13    male     C     D
10  c17  female     C     D
11   c7  female     C     D
12   c8    male     C     D
13  c12    male     E     F
14  c17  female     E     F
15   c8    male     E     F
```

Answer (score 0):

[Set](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) the pairs as index, create a multiindex from the columns, [stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) the lowest level, then [drop duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) based on pairs, cgen and cit

```
df = df.set_index(["pair1", "pair2"])

df.columns = df.columns.str.split("(\d)", expand=True).droplevel(-1)
df.columns.names = names = ["text", "numbers"]

(
    df.stack()
    .reset_index()
    .drop_duplicates(["pair1", "pair2", "cgen", "cit"])
    .sort_values(["pair1", "pair2", "numbers"], ignore_index=True)
    .drop("numbers", 1)
)



text    pair1   pair2   cgen    cit
0        A          B   male    c1
1        A          B   female  c2
2        A          B   male    c5
3        A          B   female  c25
4        A          B   male    c26
5        A          C   male    c1
6        A          C   female  c2
7        A          C   female  c3
8        C          D   male    c1
9        C          D   female  c7
10       C          D   male    c8
11       C          D   male    c13
12       C          D   female  c17
13       E          F   male    c8
14       E          F   male    c12
15       E          F   female  c17
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a more idiomatic way, but I think this works: split `df` into two DataFrames, one corresponding to "c1" and one to "c2", but both with the same pair columns.  Then `concat`:

```
df1 = df[['cit1','cgen1','pair1','pair2']]
df2 = df[['cit2','cgen2','pair1','pair2']]

df1.columns = ['cit','cgen','pair1','pair2']
df2.columns = ['cit','cgen','pair1','pair2']

output = pd.concat([df1,df2])
```

But this has some duplicates compared to your desired output, so I removed them.  And credit to @jezrael 's answer b/c I didn't understand how the output was sorted:

```
output = output[~output.duplicated()].sort_values(['pair1','pair2','cit']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Result:

```
    cit    cgen pair1 pair2
0    c1    male     A     B
1    c2  female     A     B
2   c25  female     A     B
3   c26    male     A     B
4    c5    male     A     B
5    c1    male     A     C
6    c2  female     A     C
7    c3  female     A     C
8    c1    male     C     D
9   c13    male     C     D
10  c17  female     C     D
11   c7  female     C     D
12   c8    male     C     D
13  c12    male     E     F
14  c17  female     E     F
15   c8    male     E     F
```